# How to do Reverse Geocoding in react native

Tags: react-native, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get my current location in react native, using [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation) I get latitude and longitude of my location. Now I want to convert them into the location's address without using the Google API key.

Is there any way to convert latitude longitude into an address without using the Google API key?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways to convert lon/lat to address without using Google Maps API. Search `reverse geocoding api` and you'll find a bunch of alternatives.

A few months ago I was being overcharged by Google for reverse geocoding API requests. So I switched to [Here](https://developer.here.com/). They have a [free tier](https://developer.here.com/pricing) that offers 250k requests/months, which works for my app. See the docs here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode
This will give you highly detailed address data (unlike ip-api.com suggested by Muhammad).

Here is the wrapper function I use to call the API:

```
function getAddressFromCoordinates({ latitude, longitude }) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const url = `https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?apiKey=${HERE_API_KEY}&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=${latitude},${longitude}`
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((resJson) => {
        // the response had a deeply nested structure :/
        if (resJson
          && resJson.Response
          && resJson.Response.View
          && resJson.Response.View[0]
          && resJson.Response.View[0].Result
          && resJson.Response.View[0].Result[0]) {
          resolve(resJson.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.Label)
        } else {
          resolve()
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('Error in getAddressFromCoordinates', e)
        resolve()
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can tell me what is `${AppConfig.HERE_REVERSE_GEOCODER_URL}` here?

Comment: @Iffat I updated my answer to show the url. It's the endpoint you need to call for the reverse geocoding API. You can also find it in the Here docs I liked.

Answer (score 7):

there are many alternatives you can search reverse geocoding API

## Solution 1:

**By using Google map key**

```
const myApiKey="Key Received from Google map"

function getAddressFromCoordinates({latitude, longitude}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' +
        latitude +
        ',' +
        longitude +
        '&key=' +
        myApiKey,
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.status === 'OK') {
          resolve(responseJson?.results?.[0]?.formatted_address);
        } else {
          reject('not found');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

## Solution 2:

**By using Here Plateform key**

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/example-reverse-geocoding.html

They have a [free tier](https://developer.here.com/pricing) which gives us **250k requests/months**  free quota

```
const HERE_API_KEY="Key Received from Here Plateform"

function getAddressFromCoordinates({latitude, longitude}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = `https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?apiKey=${HERE_API_KEY}&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=${latitude},${longitude}`
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((resJson) => {
        if (resJson
          && resJson.Response
          && resJson.Response.View
          && resJson.Response.View[0]
          && resJson.Response.View[0].Result
          && resJson.Response.View[0].Result[0]) {
          resolve(resJson.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.Label)
        } else {
          reject('not found')
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        reject(e);
      })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
const getAddressFromCoordinates  = async(latitude, longitude) => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=key`);
          const json = await response.json();
          setRealAddress(json.results[0]?.formatted_address);
          return json?.results[0]
          // return json.movies;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue with my react native project and then came here for answers, the first upvoted answer really helped me but I couldn't get it to work on my end so I went to their website and read their docs and it seems they updated the API's response, I was able to get it to work from the updated response and the code is below :

```
function getAddressFromCoordinates({ latitude, longitude }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = `https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocodeat=${latitude}%2C${longitude}&lang=en-US&apiKey=${HERE_API_KEY}`;

      fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resJson => {
          if (resJson.items[0].title) {
            resolve(resJson.items[0].address.label);
          } else {
            reject('not found');
          }
        })
        .catch(e => {
          reject(e);
        });
    });
  }
```